# Requesting page from site with ASP.NET on server side

Tags: python, http, parsing

I've written an application in Python for crawling web-site that uses ASP.NET on server site.

That's what I've been doing (just copied HTTP headers and body from browser, because I can see no other way of doing that):

( And it worked! Some time ago.. But now it aborts with "connection timeout". )

```
def SBPageLoader(keyWord):
    headers = {'Host': 'www.sberbank-ast.ru' ,
    'Connection': 'keep-alive' ,
    'Content-Length': '46203',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0' ,
    'Origin': 'http://www.sberbank-ast.ru' ,
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux i686)' ,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' ,
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' ,
    'Referer': 'http://www.sberbank-ast.ru/purchaseList.aspx' ,
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch' ,
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' ,
    'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8' ,
    'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=d4ki4j55hsq3km45b4qbrgjs; __utma=99173852.1461595200.1340564818.1341685237.1341758931.11; __utmb=99173852.4.9.1341758978151; __utmc=99173852; __utmz=99173852.1340564818.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)'
    }
#....( here is lots of data with undefined meaning - what is it? )......
    data = '_EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=........&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUJMzUwNDEzMjgxD2QWAmYPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgQCAQ9kFgICAg8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCBQ9kFgICAQ9kFgYCAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgwCFQ8PZBYGHgdjb250ZW50BRRsZWFmOnB1YmxpY2RhdGVzdGFydB4JbWF4bGVuZ3RoBQIxMB4FY2xhc3MFCCBkYXRlUlVTZAIXDw9kFgYfAQUSbGVhZjpwdWJsaWNkYXRlpurchID400=887031'
    data = data.replace("Toyota", keyWord) # haha - cattlecode

    log("Strat loading http://www.sberbank-ast.ru/purchaseList.aspx ...")
    req = urllib2.Request('http://www.sberbank-ast.ru/purchaseList.aspx', data, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    page = response.read()
    log(".. Loading is finished")
```

Now, even if I replace old body and headers with new ones - same thing happen.

Any ideas about what's wrong with it are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using cookielib

Answer (score 1):

The session for the website has probably expired. If you look at the cookies you can see that it is passing in a session identifier:

> 'Cookie': '**ASP.NET_SessionId=d4ki4j55hsq3km45b4qbrgjs**;
>   __utma=99173852.1461595200.1340564818.1341685237.1341758931.11; __utmb=99173852.4.9.1341758978151; __utmc=99173852; __utmz=99173852.1340564818.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)'

(By the way, the rest of the cookies can be ignored, they are actually Google Analytics cookies which are only used client side in JavaScript.)

Most servers have sessions that expire if they are not used for a certain period of time. If the sessions are stored in memory on the server, then they would be lost if the server was rebooted.

You may need to go back to the site in your browser and get a new session identifier, or build that part into your crawler.

If you want to build it into your crawler then you need to take a look at storing the cookies that you receive back from the server.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems to me that there's something else here. I've updated all headers and http-body. And the thing I can't understand is that server doen't answer at all. Even with error code or empty page.

Comment: Nope, it simply doesn't create new connection from me until previous is dead.

Comment: It could just be that something is wrong with their webservers. If you didn't change anything then it's probably not your fault.